# Get VS javascript intellisense for js in a different file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

So I've defined my 'enum' at the top of my javascript file as so:

```
var loaderOptions = { "SHOW": 0,
    "CHANGEPAGE": 1,
    "HIDE": 2
};
```

I wanted this enum to be used in a utility function used later ( showLoader(miliseconds, elementOrPageID, option, textMessage, callbackFunc) {}  ).

This is all working fabulously as I have intellisense when I call the enum/variable [image]

HOWEVER, I would like to move the function and its enum OUT of my main file into a utility file ... I can make this work just fine but I lose the intellisense ... any tricks to be able to keep this ability?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Add a References Directive on top of the JavaScript file

```
/// <reference path="file1.js" />
```

[MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ERMAHGERD!!!  This is why I love Stack!  Thank you!  EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Comment: /// <reference path="angular.js" />

Comment: /// <reference path="~/assets/js/userData.js" />  works if it is in a different folder location

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 14):

[Mads Kristensen's blog post](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) on the `_references.js` file shows a more recent way of handling this than the one epascarello mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863533/575530). Here's a quote from Mads's post:

> Enter _references.js.
>
> This file must (by default) be located in a folder at the root called /scripts/. That's the naming convention. Any file located at /scripts/_references.js is automatically added to global Intellisense. This is now the only file we need for triple-slash references. Here's what the contents of this file may look like:

```
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.6.2.js" /> 
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" /> 
/// <reference path="bootstrap.js" /> 
/// <reference path="respond.js" />
```

> Just a bunch of references. This is also the only file that is included in Intellisense by default at all times.

Comment: A good answer then, so I won't vote it down, but, this answer is no longer correct. _references.js has not been accepted since Visual Studio 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/javascript/javascript-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#notable-changes-from-visual-studio-2015