# Link HTML File To Java Script File

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, reference, intellisense

Hey everybody I know this sounds like a bit of a newb question, but I am new to the concept of using an external Java Script file.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to work on a HTML 5 website and I wrote an external java script file that will be used with my index.html file. I have already linked my Java Script file to my HTML file and am able to use the functions in that file just fine; however, I would really like to link the HTML file to my Java Script file that way Intellisense will still work when I am editing the external Java Script file the same way it would work if I was working with an embedded script.

For example say I had a div tag named "myAwesomeDiv" in my HTML page that I wanted to reference in one of my Java Script functions. If I had this function somewhere in my HTML page I could just start typing "myAwesome" and Intellisense would come up with that div name as an option which is very handy; however, I am using an external Java Script file, so if I started typing that div name while in the JS file nothing would come up because it can't see anything in my HTML file.

So what I am asking is there anyway to link my HTML file to the JS file so that it can look at elements in my HTML file and provide suggestions for me while I am typing inside of my JS file?

I have already tried referencing the HTML file at the top of my JS file like this.

```
///<reference path="index.html" />
```

This didn't seem to do anything for me :(

Any help would greatly be appreciated as I am very spoiled with Intellisense, but I also love the idea of using an external Java Script file.

Comment: What is the question exactly? so much text but... Are you asking about `<script src="index.js"></script>`?

Comment: What are you trying to get Intellisense to auto-complete? In which file?

Comment: @enhzflep from the post: _I have already linked my Java Script file to my HTML file and am able to use the functions in that file just fine_. The question is about how to get Intellisense working, though I'm not clear on _what_, exactly, isn't working. Make sure you read the question before you get too indignant about it.

Comment: @slister, @mathletics - Yes indeed, perhaps I should. I don't use VS, hate it with a passion since the 2005 version, yet when I search google (and re-read the question properly) I get what appears to be the answer.. In the ***html*** file, you add `///<reference path='yourJsFile.js'/>` You add this immediately above `<script src='yourJsFile.js'></script>` Is this not the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863461/get-vs-javascript-intellisense-for-js-in-a-different-file

Comment: Not exactly. Sorry maybe I should be a little more specific. I want to do the opposite of that @enhzflep. I want Intellisense to be able to reference my HTML file while I am working on my Java Script file. For example I would like it to come up with form elements and what not from my HTML file while I am working on my Java Script file basically the same way it would if the Java Script was embedded in the HTML document. Does that make sense?